# How to put users in queue using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I have created a dynamic data website in visual studio 2010 using C# and ASP.NET

When a user creates a request (for example a request for software installation), i would like that request to go into some kind of queue. So that i can check the users request and either allow or deny it.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: A queue for what. to view a list on a page. Or something that some other software can automatically query to receive instructions to perform some task. what have you tried already ?

Comment: You have described authorization process. As it is right now, your post has little to do with queueing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all request in a database, and add a flag that it has not been processed

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response! I have tried this sollution and it work for me. Thanks again !